# data tables search and pagination not working after rendering server side

Tags: php, ajax, search, pagination, datatables

I am currently rendering a table using the following code (which renders the table and the info fine, but the pagination or search features do not work)

```
        $('#example').DataTable({

        "bDestroy":true,
        "iDisplayLength":5,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayStart ":5,
        "sAjaxSource": '/path/to/controller/method',
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

             $.ajax({
                "dataType" : 'json',
                "type" : "POST",
                "url" : sSource,
                "data": {requested_date: today}, // today is variable I obtain elsewhere
                "success" : function(data){
                    str = JSON.stringify(data);
                    str = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
                    $('tbody').empty();
                    $.each(JSON.parse(str), function (i, result) {
                        $('tbody').append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + result.id + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.name + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.age + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.created_at + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + result.other_info + '</td>' +

                            '<td>' + result.message + '</td>' +

                            '</tr>'
                        )
                    });

                }
            });
         }
    });
```

I need to pass todays date to my controller method in order to get the information needed, I then need to append the body of the table to show this info. What exactly am I doing wrong? The table renders perfectly but the use of the data tables functionality is gone when I do this. I know the aoData is relevant to making the pagination and search work, but how exactly am I working that into my code?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a very similar issue. BUT I think the first issue is that you are mixing legacy dataTable with 1.10+.

In your declaration: $('#example').DataTable({

if you declare your datatable with Capital D, you would need to pass in the options in the later format such as "serverSide" instead of "bServerSide". See example at https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

I still encounter similar problem with my pagination not showing up (say there are 100 totalRecords, 10 recordsFiltered, and array of 10 data) BUT It was not giving me the correct number of paginations and the "next" button is disabled.

For your case, pick wether to use the legacy datatables OR the 1.10+ version with "DataTable" like what you did.

I hope it helps a little bit!

Answer (score 0):

> The error message http://datatables.net/tn/3 states the problem precisely.
>
> You need to destroy the table first, see http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy. You can do that with $("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy() (DataTables 1.9.x) or $("#example").DataTable().destroy() (DataTables 1.10.x).

```
function myfunction()
{
     
        // Destroy the table
        // Use $("#example").DataTable().destroy() for DataTables 1.10.x
        $("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy()

        $("#example").dataTable({
           // ... skipped ...
        });
    
}
```

> Alternatively, if you're using DataTables 1.10.x, you can initialize the new table with additional option "destroy": true, see below.

```
function myfunction()
{
     
        $("#example").dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            // ... skipped ...
        });
    
}
```